# Testing onChange event in Mui tab component with jest

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm trying to te`st my functionality which gets called when the value state changes , Im not sure on how to write the unit test case for the scenario.

```
import { TabProps } from "./Tab.types";
import {AntTabs,AntTab} from "./TabComponentStyles"

function TabComponent(props:TabProps) {

const { handleChange, value, Data } = props



return (
  
        <AntTabs
        data-testid="tab"
        value={value}
        sx={{ ml: 2 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="ant example"
        > 
         {Data.map((item, index) => {
            return <AntTab data-testid="childtab" label={item.name} key={index} />;
          })}


        </AntTabs>
    )
}

export default TabComponent
```

> Below is how the component is implemented in the parent component

> const [Tabvalue,setTabValue] = useState(0);

> const handleChange=(event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number)=>{

```
      // value for tabmenu 
      setTabValue(newValue);

    }
```

> 

Answer (score -1):

if you would like to verify `handleChange` should be called when have change event on `AntTab`

first of all you need to mocking the external dependency (in this case is `AntTab` and `AntTabs`).

```
import {render, fireEvent, screen} from '@testing-library/react'

// mocking external dependencies, 
jest.mock('./TabComponentStyles', () => ({
    AntTab: ({label}) => <div data-label={label}/>,
    AntTabs: ({value, sx, onChange,children}) => <div onClick={onChange} data-testid='test-ant-tabs'>
        {children}
    </div>
}))

describe('<TabComponent />', () => {
    const mockProps = {
        handleChange: jest.fn(),
        value: 0,
        Data: ['item1', 'item2']
    }
    it('should called function `handleChange` when `AntTabs` component has even onChange', () => {

        render(<TabComponentStyles  {...mockProps}/>)

        const antTabsElem = screen.getByTestId('test-ant-tabs')
        fireEvent.click(antTabsElem)

        expect(mockProps.handleChange).toHaveBeenCalled()

    })
})
```

as the code above, on mocking part, we will pass the value(in this case is `onChange` props value) that we pass on the implementation code to even `onClick`, after that we gonna make the event like a `fireEvent.click`, when this function is working, it will call something that you pass on the mocking part(in this case, it will called function that you pass into the `onChange` props).